# Find the next character: r,t,h,j,m,?

Tags: pattern, letter-sequence

In a series of characters which looks like this:

> **r, t, h, j, m, ...**

Find out what character comes next.

Comment: 18,20,8,10,13,15 = r,t,h,j,m,o
I can't quite figure the reason why it goes from 20 to 8 though...

Comment: The pattern repeats itself. **r, t, h, j, m, r, t, h, j, m, ...**

Comment: Are you using English alphabet?

Comment: answer is **,**

Comment: No one's telling this poor dude why all the down votes, typically prediction questions like this are unappreciated as there are litteraly infinite possibilities that one could argue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the word "character" is used instead of "letter", the series could be:

> r, t, h, j, m, **comma**
> because this is almost "right and diagonal down and repeat" on a standard QWERTY keyboard.
>
> If this is the intended method, a more consistent series would have been **t, y, h, j, m, comma**

Answer (score 2):

You can get r,t,h,j,m,o,r,t,h,j,m,o by doing the following formula and converting the number to the correct position in the alphabet:

((((Round(n/2)+1)%3)*5)+8)+(2*((n+1)%2))